# Can´t retrieve data from database to jsp using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

Im trying to show data in a table retrieving it from my Oracle databse but it wont show up.

Heres the code im using.

Servlet to list data:

```
package org.sistemamedico.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.sistemamedico.db.Conexion;

@WebServlet("/ServletListarMedicamento.do")
public class ServletListarMedicamento extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)            throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher despachador = null;
    req.setAttribute("listaMedicamento", Conexion.getInstancia().listar("From Medicamento"));
    despachador = req.getRequestDispatcher("sistemamedico/farmacia.jsp");
    despachador.forward(req, resp);
}
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doPost(req, resp);
}
}
```

Database connection with list method:

```
package org.sistemamedico.db;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class Conexion {
private SessionFactory sesion;
private static Conexion instancia;
public static synchronized Conexion getInstancia(){
    return (instancia==null)?new Conexion():instancia;
}
public Conexion(){
    try {
        sesion=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void closeSession()throws HibernateException {
    try {
        if (sesion.isClosed()==false | sesion.getCurrentSession().isOpen()) {
            sesion.close();
            sesion.getCurrentSession().close();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        throw new HibernateException(ex);
    }
}

public List<Object> listar(String consulta){
    Session miSesion=sesion.getCurrentSession();
    List<Object> lista=null;
    miSesion.beginTransaction();
    lista=miSesion.createQuery(consulta).list();
    miSesion.getTransaction().commit();
    return lista;
}
public List<Object> autenticarUsuario(String nick,String contraseña){
    Session miSesion=sesion.getCurrentSession();
    List<Object> lista=null;
    miSesion.beginTransaction();
    lista=miSesion.createQuery("From Usuario u where u.nick='"+nick+"' and contraseña='"+contraseña+"'").list();
    miSesion.getTransaction().commit();
    return lista;
}
public void agregar (Object agregar){
    Session session=sesion.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(agregar);
    session.getTransaction().commit();  
}
public Object buscar(Class<?> clase,int id){
    Session session=sesion.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Object obj=session.get(clase, id);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return obj;
}
public Object buscar(Class<?> clase,String id){
    Session session=sesion.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Object obj=session.get(clase, id);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return obj;
}
}
```

My table in JSP:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Descripcion</th>
                  <th>Proveedor</th>
                  <th>Fecha Vencimiento</th>
                  <th>Precio</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <c:forEach items="${listaMedicamento}" var="medicamento">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${medicamento.getNombre()}</td>
                        <td>${medicamento.getDescripcion()}</td>
                        <td>${medicamento.getIdProveedor().getNombre()}</td>
                        <td>${medicamento.getFechaVencimiento()}</td>
                        <td>${medicamento.getPrecio()}</td>
                    </tr>
                 </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I already put the taglib so c:foreach can work but it wont show me any data.

Comment: Are you sure your SQL "From" statement is retrieving data?

Answer (score 0):

When I had used a `<c:forEach>`, I used `<c:out>` to display each cell. See if this works.

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${listaMedicamento}" var="medicamento">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${medicamento.getNombre()}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${medicamento.getDescripcion()}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${medicamento.getIdProveedor().getNombre()}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${medicamento.getFechaVencimiento()}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${medicamento.getPrecio()}"/</td>
                </tr>
      </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Please try to see whether the list data from db is proper  by printing out in Servlet class.
               **Step2:** If the data is proper, Please check the object type/structure in the list and verify that you are  properly iterating it in JSP. 
 **Step3:** If the list is empty, we have to modify the query and debug further. 
**Example**: List listFromDb = Conexion.getInstancia().listar("From Medicamento");
System.out.println("the data from db is :"+listFromDb);
req.setAttribute("listaMedicamento", listFromDb);

Comment: Thanks, tried printing out in console the list but it doesnt show anything.

Comment: please verify the count of records in table first as list is empty. Please add getCount method in Conexion class and try to see the no of records in the table-Medicamento  .                                                            Example: ( (Integer) session.createQuery("select count(*) from Medicamento").iterate().next() ).intValue()

Comment: Are you able to verify the no of records in table using select count query?